# Creating element in React for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am trying to create a button with a click event in React js. I cannot use JSX since it is not available in Rails. While creating element, it is firing error "Invalid component element."

```
var csearch_btn = React.createClass({
handleClick: function(index) {
  console.log('content_input clicked');
}
,
render: function() {
return '<button class="btn btn-pill bg-color-blue-4" onClick=   
{this.handleClick()}>Search</button>';
}
});

   ReactDOM.render(csearch_btn ,   
  document.getElementById('content_Search_Btn'));
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with Rails but this might be interesting: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/30/use-react-and-jsx-in-ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: Thanks buddy. It helped me.

Comment: If you use the react_rails gem, it adds JSX compilation to the asset pipeline along with several other useful features for integrating more harmoniously with Rails.   https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails -- Will likely be a huge time saver for you.